# Node MQTT client won't connect to MQTT server but CLI mosquitto_pub can

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, mqtt.js

Trying to figure out why MQTT Node library can't connect to MQTT server w/ username, password even tho it works perfectly fine using the CLI commands.

**CLI Publish**

```
 mosquitto_pub -t testtopic -h localhost -p 1883  -u admin -P adminpassword -m "test"
```

This works as expected and I've verified that messaages are getting to the server, and I can consume them via `mosquitto_sub` or from NiFi for example.

**connect-send-mqtt.js**

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');

var local = {
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'adminpassword',
}

const client = mqtt.connect(`tcp://localhost:1883`,local);

client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected')

  setInterval(e =>{
    sendReportToMQTT()
  },5000)

})

client.on('error', () => {console.error("error")})

function sendReportToMQTT() {

  let reportFile = {};
  let stringifiedReport = JSON.stringify({test:"Message"});

  client.publish("amq.topic", stringifiedReport);
  console.log('published report!', message);
}
```

I just continue to receive `Connection refused: Not authorized`.

I'd provide more information I can't think of anything else interesting. All localhost as you can see. I've doublechecked syntax for mqtt options from [their github](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#mqttclientstreambuilder-options), and I've seen examples like this elsewhere.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: If the messages "are in fact getting to the server" then the client is connecting. Are you testing with just the code above, and can you please check the mosquitto logs (lets see if it is rejecting any connections).

Comment: The error of `not authorized` implies it's not the URL but the username/password that are wrong

Comment: @Brits I mean when I use the **CLI Publish**, the messages get to the server, meaning the user/pass have to be valid. but the node mqtt client does not connect

Comment: What do the broker logs show?